# Getting XML formatted output but not JSON output from WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

When I call method `XMLData` with `WebMessageFormat.Xml` I get response like this:

[image]

When I call method `XMLData` with `WebMessageFormat.Json` I get response like this:

[image]

WCF Code:

```
namespace RestService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRestServiceImpl
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string XMLData(string id);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]     
        string JSONData();
    }

    public class RestServiceImpl : IRestServiceImpl
    {
        #region IRestServiceImpl Members

        public string XMLData(string id)
        {
            return "You requested product " + id;
        }

        public string JSONData()
        {
            return "You requested product ";
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RestService.RestServiceImpl">
        <endpoint name="jsonEP"
                  address=""
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="json"
                  contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="json">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is a serialization format of an unordered collection of key:value pairs with the ':' character separating the key and the value, comma-separated and usually enclosed in braces(Objects), brackets(Arrays) or quotes(string)

Although what you are having for response is in JSON format, it is also a plain text in string format! There's no object/array to serialize and there's no key/value pair for response, that's why firebug does not show any JSON preview in the network tab

Try to return some complex object in your REST service and you'll get to see the JSON response preview in the Firebug debugger:

```
public class RestServiceImpl : IRestServiceImpl
{
    public JSONResponse JSONData(string id)
    {
        return new JSONResponse { Response = "You requested product " + id };
    }
}

public class JSONResponse
{
    public string Response { get; set; }
}
```